# ALB configuration to Rasa server getting unhealthy checks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa

We are trying to configure ALB for the AWS EC2 docker containerized Rasa Server with Port 5005.

We have attached the Rasa Server to the ALB but we are receiving unhealthy checks with 504 timeout gateway although we are getting the response from the Rasa server Ip address.

We are not able to get the health checks from the ALB after configuring the '/' path. But in the browser, we are getting the healthy response if we use the Rasa Server IP  address instead of the ALB DNS name.

Private subnets, security groups and the VPC are configured as same in the ALB and the Rasa Server.

Can you help us here

Answer (score 0):

The 504 timeout indicates that the Load Balancer is unable to speak to the target group.

As you're able to speak to the container (which indicates it is running), the most likely reason is that one of the security groups of the host is not providing inbound access from the load balancer.

Ensure that it can provide inbound access to your load balancer on the specific port.

Other than this check that the target group is configured to use the correct port within the target group, it is easy to accidentally set as port 80 which would lead to it attempting to either health check or service traffic via port 80